# Trying to create a dog calculate, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, visual-studio

So I'm new to JS and trying to create a basic dog calculator to find out dogs age in human years.
1 year for dogs = 7 human years.

I know I'm close because whenever I run it in console, I get "Your dog is NaN years old in dog years!!".

Here's my code:

```
Dog Age:<input type="number" id="dogage">


<button onclick="calculateDogAge()"></button>

<h2 id= "humanyears"></h2>


function calculateDogAge(age) {
    //1 year for dogs is equivalent to  7 human years
    var dogYears= 7 * age;
    console.log("Your dog is " + dogYears + " years old in dog years!!");
}
document.getElementById("dogage").innerHTML= humanyears [age];
```

Comment: `onclick="calculateDogAge()"` <= does that look like a problem?

Comment: paired with `function calculateDogAge(age) {}`

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to pass in the age.  You need to get the age with `document.querySelector('#dogage').value` and then use it.

Comment: What do you mean by "pass in the age"? So I need to use querySelector and then the age? I'm sorry I'm having a hard time understanding.

Comment: `function calculateDogAge(age) {}` <= that `age` there, that's a function argument.  It means when you call that method, it expects you to give it something, like `calculateDogAge(12)`.  You're onclick is not doing that.  So that variable doesn't have a value when you try to do `7 * age`.  But you shouldn't pass it in because your button doesn't know what the age is.  The value of the age is whatever the user types in your input element.  So to get that, you have to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

You dont say where you call your function, but ¡its right!.

you can return the dogage directly in the function:

```
function calculateDogAge(age) {
    //1 year for dogs is equivalent to  7 human years
    var dogYears= 7 * age;
    return dogYears;
}
```

You wrote:

```
document.getElementById("dogage").innerHTML= humanyears [age];
```

which makes no sense, what is humanyears? is it an array?

To get the input number, you first get the input as an element, and get its value, like this:

```
var inputAge=document.getElementById("dogage").value;
```

and then you call the function:

```
var dogAge=calculateDogAge(inputAge);
```

and finally you write the dog age, maybe in your h2 like this:

```
document.getElementById("humanyears").innerHTML=dogAge;
```

Comment: I finally got it! It's displaying correctly when I look in console, but not sure why the output isn't appearing to my h2 on the page.

Comment: Ok I finally got it working everyone, thank you so much. It wasn't displaying on page because I had to move a bracket }

Comment: hope you get it!